# file in folder but filenotfound exception

Tags: java, file

I have declared the files in the same folder,yet it gives me a "File NotFound Exeption".The file name is correct .I get the same error if i try to use other methods of accessing the file information.I am not sure why.Is there an Logical mistake.I learned it from the site http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaIO/article.html>

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FilesC {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String returnValue = "";
          FileReader file = null;
          String fileName = "test.txt";
          try {
            file = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              returnValue += line + "\n";
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          } finally {
            if (file != null) {
              try {
                file.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore issues during closing 
              }
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Thanks it worked but one more thing >I have only one line in my file .When i do the following thing to my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FilesC {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String returnValue = "";
          FileReader file = null;
          String fileName = "C:\\Users\\KingKong\\Desktop\\WorkSpace\\Victory\\src\\test.txt";
            String line = "";

          try {
            file = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              returnValue += line + "\n";

            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          } finally {
            if (file != null) {
              try {
                file.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore issues during closing 
              }
            }
          }
          System.out.println(line);
          System.out.println(returnValue);

    }
}
```

It gives me output:

```
null
myLine
```

How is this possible.If there is only one line doesnt the line and returnValue must have he same value?

Comment: Try using the absolute path like `"D:/foderName/file.txt"`

Comment: The `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` will set the line variable to null once it reaches the end of the file. That explains why line and retunrValue are different.

Answer (score 0):

You file "test.txt" need to be exactly in the same folder as the compile .jar file.

I suppose it is not. I trust more java than you :-)

To be sure, try using the absolute path

```
String fileName = "c:/mydir/test.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The last iteration in the this loop clears the line:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   returnValue += line + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the output contain null because the variable line contain null:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  returnValue += line + "\n";
}
```

when the while finish the line will be null

Answer (score -1):

A file not found exception can be thrown if you do not have the permissions necessary to open the requested file.

Comment: Why the down vote? While the probable cause of the failure was already given (path confusion) an alternative possibility still existed. $ chmod 0 test.txt 
$ java FilesC
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (Permission denied)
 at FilesC.main(FilesC.java:19)